# Framer Motion. At the end of the animation, the element gets too large

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

Scale of the element at the end of the animation "jumps"
[Video](https://files.fm/f/mdx2xgzgq)

[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-shockley-yjr35q?file=/src/components/CardModal/CardModal.jsx)

```
<ModalOverlay onClick={toggleModal}>
    <motion.div
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
        layoutId={dragon.name}
        animate={{
            scale: 1.5,
        }}
    >
        <CardModal dragon={dragon} />
    </motion.div>
</ModalOverlay>
```

The element should scale up to scale(1.5), but at the last moment its scale reaches 2+ and abruptly becomes 1.5

Comment: Can you share the version of framer-motion/React you're using?

Comment: @AndrewUsher I'm using React 18.2.0 and Framer Motion 10.15.1

Comment: The sandbox does not seem to be available for other people

Comment: @RubenSmn Sorry, My sandbox is giving an error so I found an alternative, hope this helps
https://stackblitz.com/github/Malberee/dragon-eye?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCardModal%2FCardModal.jsx

Comment: @RubenSmn I fixed my codeSandbox, please check it out
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-shockley-yjr35q?file=/src/components/CardModal/CardModal.jsx)

Comment: It could be something with the `layoutId` if you remove that from the `Card` it will scale fine